# How add List-Unsubscribe header to native mail() function of PHP

Tags: php, function, email, native, list-unsubscribe

i've tested my spamscore on https://www.mail-tester.com/. It was good, but as an aprovement it suggested :

> Your message does not contain a List-Unsubscribe header The
> List-Unsubscribe header is required if you send mass emails, it
> enables the user to easily unsubscribe from your mailing list.

How do I add this to a native `mail();` function of PHP. Or is it even possible this way? (I cannot find one single simple example on the www).

Comment: Google is your friend. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2369.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add additional headers with the [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail) function.

```
$headers = [
    'From: thisisme@example.net',
    'List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:thisisme@example.net?subject=unsubscribe>'
];

$body = 'I am the newsletter content.';

mail('recipent@example.net', 'Subject of newsletter', $body, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Comment: For unsubscribing via HTTPS, use `List-Unsubscribe: <https://example.org/unsubscribe/randomtoken>` + `List-Unsubscribe-Post: List-Unsubscribe=One-Click` per [RFC 8058](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8058)

Comment: @Luc, thanks for the info. But also note the quote `But anti-
   spam software often fetches all resources in mail header fields
   automatically, without any action by the user, and there is no
   mechanical way for a sender to tell whether a request was made
   automatically by anti-spam software or manually requested by a user.`. So passing the URL may not be a good solution.

Comment: This is literally the problem being solved in that RFC by introducing the POST body `List-Unsubscribe=One-Click`. Without that request body being present, indeed the PHP server cannot know whether it is just a link scanner making the request. Scanners typically perform HEAD/GET requests, not a POST with this standardised unsubscribe text if it is not trying to unsubscribe the user, and if it were, it could also send an email...